# How to prevent "*" route from running with the routes defined previously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, error-handling, backend

I defined my app routes in that order

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const error = new AppError(
    `This ${req.originalUrl} is not on the server`,
    404,
  );
  next(error);
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);
```

The AppError is a class to customize the error object and the globalErrorHandler is function that send the error response according to the error object comes from `next()`.

My problem is that the '*' routes runs with all the routes that I handled previous with the tourRouter. I don't know why this happens. It wasn't doing this, just happens once and still happening until the time I wrote this problem.

NOTE: Postman gives me the correct response from the routes I defined, but the terminal in VSC gives me the *"cannot send header after it sent"* error.

I don't know what to do since I don't know why the error happened.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is running? The error suggesting something else. I would guess that the route tries to send data two times

Comment: The code is running as expected but there is an error shown in the terminal after every request
if your guessing is correct how to solve it since I just have on res.status().json() in every handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the error which was that I rapped my async router handler functions with a function called catchAsync()

```
module.exports = function (fn) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).then(next);
  }
}
```

I've updated this function to be this

```
module.exports = function (fn) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      fn(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

I made this because the catchAsync function calls the next after the fn() ends which causes to run the next middleware in the stack which is globalErrorHandler

```
app.use(globalErrorHandler);
```

to run and send another response and from here the error happened
But what makes me still confused is that the code works fine and then starts throwing errors